# Error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*'

Tags: c++

I want to make function that can return two new string that is the composition of the old one but I got an above error.

```
string constru(string num, int pos_be, int pos_end)
{
    string f_num="";
    string s_num="";
    f_num.append(num.at(pos_be));
    f_num.append(num.at(pos_end));
    num.erase(pos_be);
    num.erase(pos_end);
    for(int i=0; i<num.size();i++)
    {
        s_num.append(num.at(i));
    }
return f_num,s_num;
}
```

The Error is at the line f_num.append(num.at(pos_be)) as well as the other lines that I used append with string. Does anyone want know what went wrong here?

Comment: What's wrong with `s_num += num.at(i);`?

Comment: `num.at(i)` is a single character, while this prototype of `append` expects a character string. Use `s_num.append(1,num.at(i))` instead if you really want to use `append`, but you could get the same result with `s_num += num.at(i)`

Comment: @kuroineko, I see but the error show that invalid conversion from char to const char*. What does it mean related to above solution?

Comment: As you know, string can be represented as a `char *` in c++. So it says invalid conversion from char to char*, as you try  to convert a char to string

Comment: well the answer is in the first sentence of my previous answer. If you pass an elephant to a function that expects a mouse, the compiler usually gets unhappy about it. Hint: in C++, a char * is as different from a char as a mouse is from an elephant.

Comment: This function is possibly wrong in many ways. Logically and syntactically. Please provide a sample input arguments (i.e. a string and two integers) and what you expect as output for those arguments.

For example, for the call: constru("0123456789", 2, 5) what do you expect to get in f_num and s_num?

Comment: I highly doubt `return f_num,s_num;` is doing what you think it is doing.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is, the at function returns a char and not a string. But the append function supports a string. So you get this error. Convert the char to string before you append.

```
f_num.append(std::string(num.at(pos_be)));
f_num.append(std::string(num.at(pos_end)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f_num.append(std::string(num.at(pos_be)));
f_num.append(std::string(num.at(pos_end)));
```